# Programmatically connection string in entity framework with package manager console "Update-Database" etc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sqlconnection

i have a problem with the entity framework, the programmatically connection string and the package console manager `Update-Database` or `Add-Migration` etc.

I'm using a `configuration.xml` file for my project so that the users can change the configuration for their needs.

The problem is the programmatically connection string...

If I try to use the Update-Database command i got a result like this.

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'acme'.
Using NuGet project 'acme'.
Target database: 'acme.Models.DbContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
Using Migrationens: [..., ..., ..., ..., ...].
Appending migration: ....
```

The problem is, that the DataSource is not `.\SQLEXPRESS`. It's `My-SQLServer` for example.

Connection string is.

```
Data Source=My-SQLServer\TS;initial catalog=acme;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework
```

And the original, working config entry is this.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <!--<add name="DbContext" connectionString="Data Source=My-SQLServer\TS;initial catalog=acme;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
</connectionStrings>
```

The DbContext is...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace acme.Models
{
    public class DbContext : DbContext, IDbContextFactory<DbContext>
    {
        public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DbContext, acme.Migrations.Configuration>());
        }

        public DbContext()
            : base()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DbContext, acme.Migrations.Configuration>());
        }

        public DbSet<Base> Base { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbContext Create()
        {
            /* First try (not working) */
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            //ecsb.ProviderConnectionString = acme.ConfigFile.GetValue("ConnectionString");
            ecsb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            ecsb.ProviderConnectionString = @"application name=";

            /* Second try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (not working) */
            // Initialize the connection string builder for the
            // underlying provider.
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            // Set the properties for the data source.
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = @"My-SQLServer\TS";
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "acme";
            sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = "EntityFramework";

            // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
            string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

            // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            //Set the provider name.
            entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

            // Set the provider-specific connection string.
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

            return new DbContext(entityBuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me :)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. But I'm having the same issue.

My code used to work, but now all of a sudden it doesn't. I did move my database to a new server, but not 100% what has caused it yet. Either way, my App.Config, and my main website's Web.Config are both pointing to the correct connection string. No idea why it's ignoring them and using .\SQLEXPRESS...

Anyways, I did manage to force it use the correct connection string (temporary solution) by:

```
Add-Migration -ConnectionString "<connection string here>"
Update-Database -ConnectionString "<connection string here>"
```

It'll ask for provider name, in my case it was `System.Data.SqlClient`.